# windows 8 metro apps Convert WriteableBitmap to byte[] Issue C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to convert WriteableBitmap to byte[], but when it converts into byte[] its byte values or byte pixels are 0 (zero). plz tell me how can i solve this problem or how can get byte pixels???

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit) and call "await modifiedImage.[WaitForLoaded](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16916#309128)()" on your WriteableBitmap before you can read it.